# How to attach 10 ipv4 from remote server to home lxc containers?

Tags: linux, lxc

1. There is a remote ubuntu server with 10 ipv4.
2. There is a home ubuntu server without external ipv4. The home server has 10 lxc containers.

How to make each lxc container has own ipv4?

*Upd*
I want to connect 2 uplinks to my home server and automatically switch between them when the connection is lost on one of them. I want to get 10 more or less fall-tolerance VDSs for processing traffic of 100 Mbps each.

Comment: The most obvious is using a tunnel. That can be GRE, IPSec, OpenVPN et cetera. It can be L2 tunnel or L3; It can be via additional devices (possibly virtual) or on the Ubuntu server. Without knowing more about your set-up, it is hard to give a more specific advice.

Comment: And if you try to obfuscate your addresses when completing the question, be smart about it. For example so-called failover addresses are often in different networks but you still have to define them properly, probably also stating the host provider name and the documentation it offers about failover addresses. A complete answer could depend on this and be more difficult than if it were only a single block of addresses.

Comment: Forgot to add. I want to connect 2 uplinks to my home server and automatically switch between them when the connection is lost on one of them. I want to get 10 more or less fall-tolerance VDSs for processing traffic of 100 Mbps each. What do you advise?

Comment: That you're asking too much at once and that you should update your question, not add comments.

Comment: @A.B Thank you, It will be only a single block of addresses

Comment: Can't see this in the question... Anyway your question probably falls in the "Needs more focus" category with what you added. You should have a setup working with 1 ISP connection, then later ask what would be required to have 2 ISP connections. And writing "It will be only a single block of addresses" in the question doesn't help much figuring out your remote setup.